# Create dataframes with names from a list

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary-comprehension

I have excel files with many tabs. I want to concat all of them, one tab at a time.

I am doing:

```
mypath = "mypath"
files = os.listdir(mypath)
files = [os.path.join(mypath,f) for f in files if f[-4:]=='xlsx']

sheets = pandas.ExcelFile(files[0]).sheet_names
```

Now, say my tabs are alpha, beta, gamma, etc., I want to create a liust of dataframes df_alpha, df_beta, etc. that are the union of all the alpha tabs of the files in. my directory.

By doing:

```
for sheet in sheets:
    df = pandas.DataFrame()
    for f in files:
        df = pandas.concat([df, pandas.read_excel(f, sheet_name=sheet)])
```

I can get what I want, but of course I only have a dataframe which is the union of the last tab in each file. How can I change the code so that I have a list of dfs, each named df_alpha, df_beta, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can make do with a dictionary of dataframes, the following might help:

```py
df_dict = {}
for sheet in sheets:
    df = pandas.DataFrame()
    for f in files:
        df = pandas.concat([df, pandas.read_excel(f, sheet_name=sheet)])
    df_dict[sheet] = df
```

Later you can call the relevant `df` from the dictionary using its key, e.g. `df_dict['alpha']`.

Update: as noted in the comments by @ ALollz, the snippet above is inefficient because of multiple concats to the same dataframe. So a more efficient approach is:

```py
df_dict = {}
for sheet in sheets:
    df_dict[sheet] = pandas.concat(pandas.read_excel(f, sheet_name=sheet) for f in files)
```

Note that in this case it's OK to not define an explicit list comprehension inside `pandas.concat` (the inside expression becomes a generator).

Update 2: perhaps using the dict comprehension is more 'pythonic' (using the more common `pd` instead of `pandas`):

```py
df_dict = {
    sheet: pd.concat(pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=sheet) for f in files)
    for sheet in sheets
}
```

Here the trick is using above snippets to define `key: value` with dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea. I will try that.